# How to calculate base 100 on MYSQL select query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with stock prices. I want to query (with a specific timeframe) to analyze and get the prices back as a base 100 from the first value for that particular timeframe. Currently I have:

```
SELECT price.`date`,
    FIRST_VALUE(`NASDAQ:AAPL`) OVER (ORDER BY price.`date`) AS `Base`,
    price.`NASDAQ:AAPL`
FROM price
WHERE DATE date >= "XXX"
```

This returnes me for every row:

1. Date
2. First price of the period
3. Price for the day

Which correclty shows me the date, the price for each date and the first price for that period (Base).
How can I get a field that is the result of dividing each price / first price for the period?

I've tried

```
price.`NASDAQ:AAPL` / `Base` AS `Ratio`
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Use FIRST_VALUE(...) again in the division.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @forpas, I found a solution:

```
price.`NASDAQ:AAPL` / FIRST_VALUE(`NASDAQ:AAPL`) OVER (ORDER BY price.`date`) AS `Ratio`
```

Thanks!